# android emulator: changes on /system directory not persistent

Tags: android, fonts, android-emulator

I'm trying to install fonts on the android emulator. I can copy my TTFs on /system/fonts and overwrite exiting fonts.

But, when I reboot, all my changes are roll backed (my font files are overwritten by the originals)

How can I make my /system modifications persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response is here:
[How to restart Android emulator and preserve system data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395975/how-to-restart-android-emulator-and-preserve-system-data)